# Element's border missing after css mask-image

Tags: css, css-mask

I have applied an svg as *mask-image* to certain divs. After doing that their border is gone.

```css
.icon {
  padding:5px;
  border:5px solid #000;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-mask: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/18515/heart.svg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  -webkit-mask-size: contain;
  mask-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/18515/heart.svg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  mask-size: contain;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="icon red"></div>
  <div class="icon blue"></div>
</div>
```

Any idea why this happens?
Any solution should be based solely on css.

Comment: For those of you not seeing the issue, Chrome doesn't support `mask` without a vendor prefix so you'll need to use Firefox

Comment: For more details about it: https://caniuse.com/css-masks

Comment: well, mask apply to all the element including its border

Comment: @Sakis I would try to solve this by adding an additional div around the masked div. Pls have a look at my answer below. Hope that is the desired result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS Webkit mask image add an outline / border?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23861920/css-webkit-mask-image-add-an-outline-border)

Comment: Thanks. Added a prefixed and non prefixed css. Should work in most browsers.

Answer (score 2):

The answer for the why is trivial: The mask apply to all the element including its borders. Any part of the element will get affect by the mask even if you have a `box-shadow`

To avoid this, either use another element to create the borders or consider multiple mask to keep the border visible:

```css
.icon {
  padding:5px;
  border:5px solid #000;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-mask: 
      linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) top   /100% 5px,
      linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) bottom/100% 5px,
      linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) left  /5px 100%,
      linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) right /5px 100%,
      url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/18515/heart.svg) center/contain;
   -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="icon red"></div>
  <div class="icon blue"></div>
</div>
```

I added 4 gradients. Each one will cover a border side to keep it visible.

Comment: That is a very cool way actualy what you made. But that would only work for a square border without border radius, no ?

Comment: @MaxiGui it can work with border radius. I simply need to adjust the gradients and consider radial ones to cover the radius

Comment: Then it seems to more simple than the official usage of what I sent or at least more flexible

Answer (score 0):

I am **using an extra div wrapper** to create border around the div containing mask.

I have added comments to the code to explain my changes.

```css
.maskborder{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border:5px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.maskborder.two {
  margin-left: 10px; /* Change this to suit how much gap you want between first and second box */
}

.icon {
  padding:5px;
  border:5px solid #000;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  mask: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/18515/heart.svg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  -webkit-mask: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/18515/heart.svg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  mask-size: contain;
  -webkit-mask-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-10px, -10px) /* To offset the 5px border width so that the icons can be centred correctly in middle */
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="maskborder">
    <div class="icon red"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="maskborder two">
     <div class="icon blue"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Though i am looking for a css based solution or an explanation why this happens.

Comment: Well. The answer is CSS based. You can not add plain old CSS borders to masked element. You must apply either a masked border image. Or in your case since you want plain border CSS, we must apply it to a parent div and position on top of it. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

So after serching for a while, I finaly found out the border property for mask, it seems that you need to use an other svg as square that would make the border.

I added the below properties to `.icon`:

```
-webkit-mask-box-image: url(https://www.flaticon.com/svg/static/icons/svg/33/33879.svg) 10 repeat;
mask-border: url(https://www.flaticon.com/svg/static/icons/svg/33/33879.svg) 10 repeat;
```

I actualy find out the trick here: https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/#border-masks and just adapted it for your case.

I guess you can easily create a svg square with the border that fit and just set it in.

### DEMO

```css
.icon {
  padding:5px;
  border:5px solid #000;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-mask: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/18515/heart.svg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  -webkit-mask-size: contain;
  mask-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/18515/heart.svg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  mask-size: contain;
  -webkit-mask-box-image: url(https://www.flaticon.com/svg/static/icons/svg/33/33879.svg) 10 repeat;
  mask-border: url(https://www.flaticon.com/svg/static/icons/svg/33/33879.svg) 10 repeat;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="icon red"></div>
  <div class="icon blue"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works in chrome but not in Firefox.

Comment: Indeed. But this is really features. But even thought this is my answer, I think that answer from @TemaniAfif is much better and flexible than mine.